# Flask-SQLAlchemy distinct descending

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```py
class message(db.Model):
  _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  sender = db.Column(db.String)
  receiver = db.Column(db.String)
  content = db.Column(db.String)
  identifier = db.Column(db.String)
  date = db.Column(db.String)
```

I have this message model and I'm trying to reverse the id (for the query to start in the last element) and remove the duplicate values so it would leave me with the recent entries of message.sender

```
msg = message.query.with_entities(message.sender, message._id).filter(message.sender.in_(x.friends)).group_by(message.sender, message._id).order_by(message._id.desc())
```

Successfully did the reversing of portion of the code, but when I use the .distinct() it doesn't do anything, even .distinct(message.sender)

Case #2

```
msg = message.query.with_entities(message.sender).group_by(message.sender, message._id).distinct()
```

Successfully do the distinct portion

I tried puttin the order_by(message._id.desc()) all over the code but it is not working.

What is the right syntax for this?

Comment: The purpose of the code is to create an inbox like ui, where the query would contain  the recent messages which are sent by the user's friend to the user. If I'm doing it wrong (e.g. use another technique) please let me know. Thanks~

Comment: // SELECT DISTINCT message.sender AS message_sender, message.id AS message_id FROM message ORDER BY message.id DESC // , this is what my code executes, I checked sqlite's documentation and it is the same syntax, but still it doesn't distinctively select the query